# Progressive Web Apps alternando páginas dentro do aplicativo sem abrir browser

Tags: javascript, c#, mobile, asp.net-core, pwa

Tenho uma página mobile (http://mvc-decea.azurewebsites.net) baseada em Progressive Web Apps e feita usando Asp.Net Core.

Mas estou com o suposto problema:

Ao adicionar à tela inicial do dispositivo móvel clicando na opção de compartilhamento e adicionando à Home Screen como um ícone conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao voltar à tela home do dispositivo e abrir a página pelo ícone imitando um aplicativo progressivo é onde surge o problema, pois dentro da página tenho 2 links para outras páginas, mas quando clico em algum dos links ele abre o browser alternando entre o suposto "app" e o Safari que é o browser padrão do iPhone.

Gostaria que a mudança de página funcionasse dentro do próprio "app" sem que o browser abrisse.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com o fonte abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>stay standalone</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.5,user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(document,navigator,standalone) {
        // prevents links from apps from oppening in mobile safari
        // this javascript must be the first script in your <head>
        if ((standalone in navigator) && navigator[standalone]) {
            var curnode, location=document.location, stop=/^(a|html)$/i;
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                curnode=e.target;
                while (!(stop).test(curnode.nodeName)) {
                    curnode=curnode.parentNode;
                }
                // Condidions to do this only on links to your own app
                // if you want all links, use if('href' in curnode) instead.
                if('href' in curnode && ( curnode.href.indexOf('http') || ~curnode.href.indexOf(location.host) ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    location.href = curnode.href;
                }
            },false);
        }
    })(document,window.navigator,'standalone');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="http://google.com/">google</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // NEVER user document.write, unless for test porposes.
    document.write('<p><a href="http://'+document.location.host+'/test/">Same domain</a></p>')
</script>
<p><a href="/test/"><span>absolute path</span></a></p>
<p><a href="test/">relative path</a></p>
<p><a href="/test?http://othersite.com">http not on beginning</a></p>
<p><a href="#test">anchor</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Obtido através do [link](https://gist.github.com/kylebarrow/1042026)